# Include date range on Yahoo Financial scraper in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I found this wonderful tool made in Python to scrape data from Yahoo Finance website:
https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials

How do I pass a date range to this and include it into the script?

I would like to be able to see data on specific date range, by entering command like this:

```
python3 my_python_scraper.py TWTR, '2022-02-16', '2022-02-16'
```

Or something similar.

I can see there is a function
get_historical_price_data(start_date, end_date, time_interval)
but how do I pass dates to this script?

Any help is welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
from utils import *
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")



def parser(x):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d')


import yfinance as yf

# Get the data for the stock AAPL
start = '2020-01-01'
end = '2022-01-13'

data = yf.download('TWTR', start, end)


data = data.reset_index()
data

data.dtypes


# re-name field from 'Adj Close' to 'Adj_Close'
data = data.rename(columns={"Adj Close": "Adj_Close"})
data


data = data.loc[:,['Date','Adj_Close']]
       


plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5), dpi=100)
plt.plot(data['Date'], data['Adj_Close'], label='Twitter Stock Price')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('USD')
plt.title('Figure 2: Twitter Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir. But I am getting an error: 'No module named 'utils'.
I did this command: pip install python-utils, but again I get the same error. 
Also what should I pass to the call of this script? Thanks

Comment: Run 'pip install utils' in Anaconda Prompt. Or, just delete tat line. You don't need it. That's for something else.